# Parse JSON array in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, parsing

I have a json where an array of data is stored. Data is stored on a key-value basis. I need to parse my data into two columns, where the keys will be in the first column, and the corresponding values will be in the second.

Im using postgreSQL 15

```java
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::json_parse_type, '[{"vartanyan":1},{"ermilova":2},{"dyakonov":2},{"sokornov":2},
{"shevchenko":2},{"kreslavskaya":2},{"vartanyan":2},{"jusupov":2},{"kamenkov":2},{"davidiuk":2},{"markhipova":2},
{"voronova":2},{"karamyshev":2},{"cheryabkin":2},{"sstepanov":2},{"shumeeva":2},{"balanda":2},{"mineev":2}]');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT '[{"vartanyan":1},{"ermilova":2},{"dyakonov":2},{"sokornov":2},
            {"shevchenko":2},{"kreslavskaya":2},{"vartanyan":2},{"jusupov":2},{"kamenkov":2},{"davidiuk":2},{"markhipova":2},
            {"voronova":2},{"karamyshev":2},{"cheryabkin":2},{"sstepanov":2},{"shumeeva":2},{"balanda":2},{"mineev":2}]'::jsonb
)
SELECT key, el->>key val
FROM jsonb_array_elements((SELECT * FROM data)) el
CROSS JOIN jsonb_object_keys(el) key;
```